# ActiveRecord: Loading records with all child association eager loaded, but select the ones that any of the children hits the condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel, ransack, squeel

I have models like the following.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  # id         :integer  
  # name       :string

  has_many :assignments
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  # id         :integer  
  # finished   :boolean
  # project_id :integer  

  belongs_to :project
end
```

I want to load the projects that have any unfinished assignments, but with all assignments eager loaded. Hopefully, in a single SQL query.

Suppose I have record like the following

```
- project_1
  - assignment [finished: false]
  - assignment [finished: false]
  - assignment [finished: false]

- project_2
  - assignment [finished: true]
  - assignment [finished: true]
  - assignment [finished: true]

- project_3
  - assignment [finished: true]
  - assignment [finished: false]
  - assignment [finished: true]
```

Then the records I want is like the following.

```
- project_1
  - assignment [finished: false]
  - assignment [finished: false]
  - assignment [finished: false]

- project_3
  - assignment [finished: true]
  - assignment [finished: false]
  - assignment [finished: true]
```

Here're the questions

1. Can I achieve this using only ActiveRecord's query, `arel`, or `squeel` gem's expression?
2. If not, what kinda SQL query work for this?

I've tried the following ruby code, but it filters out the finished assignments.

```
Project.eager_load(:assignments).where('assignments.finished = ?', false)

# which results in
# 
#- project_1
#  - assignment [finished: false]
#  - assignment [finished: false]
#  - assignment [finished: false]
#
#- project_3
#  - assignment [finished: false]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you can achieve this using ActiveRecord's query as

```
@unfinished = Assignment.where(:finished => false).pluck(:project_id)

@projects = Project.includes(:assignments).where(:id => @unfinished)
```

Active Record with sql in single query as,

```
 Project.includes(:assignments).where("projects.id in (select project_id from assignments where assignments.finished = ?)", false)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But I wanted to do things in a single sql query. I'll add that to the question. You come up with anything?

Comment: @Ryo have you check my second query??